# Shooting a bullet from the direction that a rectangle is facing

Tags: java, graphics, rotation

I have a `Rectangle` object that is placed on the screen and rendered using paintComponent.
I also have a `rotation` variable that determines the rotation of the object (using right and left keys to rotate) and repaints the object on the screen using Affine Transform.

In the keyPressed method, I have this which allows me to shoot bullets:

```
else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    Bullet b = new Bullet(handler, player.x + 10, player.y - 10, ID.Bullet);
    handler.addObject(b);
    b.setDY(-3*Math.cos(player.rotation));
    b.setDX(3*Math.sin(player.rotation));
}
```

If you see where I create a new bullet, in the second line, the second and third arguments in the new Bullet() are what determines where the bullets are created. Currently they just shoot from the same position on the rectangle regardless of the rotation.

I have failed at allowing the player to shoot a bullet from the direction they are facing, so if anyone has any suggestions that would be very helpful.

Comment: what does ur rotation varible look like? (radiens/degrees)

Comment: radians. I add 0.02 when turning right and subtract 0.02 when turning left

Comment: i'll just assume you know the offset to the rectangle, if it hasn't rotated (e.g. 0.5f up)

Comment: this might help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: hey, i posted an answer that might help more than what riverman2010 proposed. While his response is mathematically correct there is no need to grasp the basic concepts of linear algebra in order to rotate something. Rotation matricies are a special type of "space transformation", that happen to not warp space but just rotate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the rotation angle and the width of the rectangle then use this information to rotate the start position of the bullet too. For example to let the start position at the right side:

x = rectMiddleX + width/2 * cos(angle)
y = rectMiddleY + width/2 * sin(angle)

If angle is 0 it will start at the right side

```
else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    Bullet b = new Bullet(handler, player.x + width/2 * cos(player.rotation), player.y - width/2 * sin(player.rotation), ID.Bullet);

//if player.x/y is in corner, add width/2 / height/2

    handler.addObject(b);
    b.setDY(-3*Math.cos(player.rotation));
    b.setDX(3*Math.sin(player.rotation));
}
```

Comment: shouldn't width/2 and height/2 be replaced by hypotenuse length?

Comment: Ok edited it. In my example the radius should be the width/2

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are trying to find the offset Vector from the player's position.

Let's assume, that you have the offset Vector, when you haven't rotated the object.
Then your task would be to rotate the given Vector by the `rotation` variable.

---

To do this we first need to look into geometry a bit. Let's think of a 2d-Vector as a triangle, that we can split into it's x and y components. We know, that the rotated Vector should have the same hypothenuse length as the original offset or in other terms the same magnitude.

This means that:

> x₀² + y₀² = x₁² + y₁²

Since:

> x² + y² = Vector-Magnitude

Your `rotation` variable keeps track of the inner angle of that "triangle vector" and hence we can describe the lengths as:

> x = sin(`rotation`) * Vector Magnitude
>
> y = cos(`rotation`) * Vector Magnitude

---

Now the only thing left to do is evalute those values. To do that, let us jump into the code, shall we?

```java
float magnitude = offset.x*offset.x + offset.y*offset.y;
float x = Math.sin(rotation) * magnitude;
float y = Math.cos(rotation) * magnitude;
Bullet b = new Bullet(handler, player.x + x, player.y + y, ID.Bullet);
```

---

### possible Errors and fixes

1. Make sure that you have the correct angle-format. The Java-Math class uses radiens for trigonometric methods.
2. There could be a constant rotation deviation, depending on what exactly you want your result to look like. This is a rather easy fix, as you just have to add this constant to the `rotation` variable. In unlikely instances you maybe also need to negate the `rotation` variable simply by using `-rotation` in the places I used `rotation` in my code.